# WPF ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate Code Behind

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I am currently using an ItemsControl template that binds to the the ViewModel to present a collection of objects.  I have a ToggleButton as part of the template.  I would like to access the object that is bound to that UI item in the collection in the code behind.

Here is the code that I have in place:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
           <ToggleButton Cursor="Hand"
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding CanToggleOnProfile}"
                         Style="{StaticResource ProfileToggleButtonStyle}" 
                         PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="OnProfileToggle">
```

I would like to in my code behind on the `OnProfileToggle` call, access that particular object in the DataTemplate and do some stuff with it, but I can't seem to figure out how to access it (what index it is at in the collection, etc).

Comment: What exactly do you need to do with the object you need to access? It is also not clear to me if you want the `Data` item or the `Visual` item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find your particular object in the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) of the **sender**:

```
private void OnProfileToggle(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleButton button = sender as ToggleButton;
    object yourItem = button.DataContext;
}
```

Of course you have to cast **yourItem** to your item class.